# How to know the GUID of a Database?

Tags: database, sharepoint, service, synchronization, guid

I follow this step by step http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx for reset the User Profile Synchronization Service but I need the GUID of the synchronization database.
I searched a lot but I didn't find anything. I need also to find the GUID of the/a service.

Thank you

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Sharepoint.se]

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know this website, thank you.

Comment: See this answer for finding GUID of databases in SQL Server 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916991/obtaining-a-unique-database-identifier-for-sql-server-2005-and-later/48433041#48433041

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Powershell to do this the way MS describes in the Technet article or the smart way:

```
$syncDBType = "Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SynchronizationDatabase"
$upaSAType = "User Profile Service Application"
$syncDB = Get-SPDatabase | where-object {$_.Type -eq $syncDBType}
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $upaSAType}

$syncDB.Unprovision() 
$syncDB.Status = "Offline"
$upa.ResetSynchronizationMachine()
$upa.ResetSynchronizationDatabase()  
$syncDB.Provision()  
restart-service SPTimerV4
```

So we actually don't look for the guid but look where the database type is the sync database type. You can find more troubleshooting gems like this on [Harbars site: “Stuck on Starting”: Common Issues with SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much but it seems $upa is NULL when I try to call ResetSynchronizationMachine(). Any idea ?

Comment: Could you look at your SQL Server via Management Studio and just look at all databases and check for e.g. "Profile DB" or "Sync DB" or something like "UserProfile..."?

Comment: Oh god... there is right Profile DB, there is right Social DB, there is right S... but, but , but ! Where is this f****** Sync DB ?! T_T  Thank you and sorry for lost time !